# Dynamically accessing an objects by a value set in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to evaluate a variable as an objects name and then retrieve the values of particular names within the object.

The object:

```
var priority = [{
    dSubDue: '1,D',
    dMS2date: "1.5,'M'",
    dMS3date: '3,M',
    dMS4date: '30,D',
    dMS5date: '1,M',
    dNotErFac: '2,W',
    dDOverview: 'N/A',
    dPreACMResp: '2,W',
    dACMdate: '2,W',
    dMS6date: '2,W',
    dMS7date: '1,M',
    dM86date: '1.5M'
}];
```

where the name of the object is priority.

When another variable, cellval, is set to the same name as the object "priority" I need to access the key values in actual priority object by using the following `cellval[0]['dMS2date']`.

If I use `eval(cellval[0]['dMS2date'])` it returns the correct values but if possible I'd prefer not to use eval.

Any Ideas? and before the admin mark this as a duplicate this is not referring to hard coding variable names as the examples used and none of the examples works in the context of the question.  It's got nothing to do with keys and values its the objects name and accessing it dynamically and not hard coded.

Comment: seems like unclear. Be more specific by giving proper explanation using examples.

Comment: You can achieve this using objects. Say your `cellval` has string `priority`. So you can create a parent object that will have all such possible objects and then `parentObject[cellval][0][...]` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you have something like 3 object viz., `priority1`, `priority2` and `priority3` and you `cellval` will hold the name of object from which you which you wish to get the value.

There is no direct way, but considering the fact that, such options will be finite and pre-defined, you can create a hashMap and the use them to get values.

Another benefit of this approach would be in reading. You can know possible options and their associated objects just by looking at the hashMap.

```js
var priority1 = [{ dSubDue: '1,D', dMS2date: "1.5,'M'", dMS3date: '3,M', dMS4date: '30,D', dMS5date: '1,M', dNotErFac: '2,W', dDOverview: 'N/A', dPreACMResp: '2,W', dACMdate: '2,W', dMS6date: '2,W', dMS7date: '1,M', dM86date: '1.5M'}];

var priority2 = [{ dSubDue: '1,D', dMS2date: "1.4,'M'", dMS3date: '3,M', dMS4date: '30,D', dMS5date: '1,M', dNotErFac: '2,W', dDOverview: 'N/A', dPreACMResp: '2,W', dACMdate: '2,W', dMS6date: '2,W', dMS7date: '1,M', dM86date: '1.5M'}];

var priority3 = [{ dSubDue: '1,D', dMS2date: "1.3,'M'", dMS3date: '3,M', dMS4date: '30,D', dMS5date: '1,M', dNotErFac: '2,W', dDOverview: 'N/A', dPreACMResp: '2,W', dACMdate: '2,W', dMS6date: '2,W', dMS7date: '1,M', dM86date: '1.5M'}];

var hashMap = {
  priority1: priority1,
  priority2: priority2,
  priority3: priority3,
}

var cellval = 'priority1';
console.log(hashMap[cellval][0].dMS2date);

cellval = 'priority2';
console.log(hashMap[cellval][0].dMS2date);

cellval = 'priority3';
console.log(hashMap[cellval][0].dMS2date);
```

Comment: interesting,  Ill give it a go